# lower central series and derived series

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, $G_i$ be the $i^{th}$ group in the lower central series. I am trying to find out connections between the derived series and the quotient of the lower central series. Explicitly, my question is the following: Assume that we know that $G'/G''$ has no torsion. Can we induce something from it on the quotient $G_2/G_3 = G'/G_3$,
or more interesting, on $G_3/G_4$? or on in general, on $G_i/G_{i+1}$?

**Edit**: Another question is the following: what can be said on $G_i/G_{i+1}$ when $G'/G''$ has only torsion elements?

Thanks

Comment: You wrote "...we know that $\;G'/G''\;$ has (no?) torsion (so it is a free abelian group)...".... the second part doesn't necessarily follow from the first one...

Comment: fixed to "no" - thanks. why's that? isn't $G'/G''$  an abelian group?

Comment: Oh, that's always true, @user75221, but not necessarily "free". Think of the rationals $\,\Bbb Q\,$ , for example.

Comment: Are you asking if $G'/G''$ being torsion-free implies $G_2/G_3$ is torsion-free?

Comment: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=255650 Gives an example where $G'/G''$ is free abelian (of infinite rank), and $G_i/G_{i+1}$ alternates between free abelian (of finite rank) and the direct product of free abelian (of finite rank) with a finite elementary abelian 2 group. Kind of neat how $G_i/G_{i+1}$ doesn't have much control on $G_{i+1}/G_{i+2}$.

Comment: Well, I'm asking what kind of relations you have between $G'/G''$, $G/G'$ and the quotients of the LCS, given that $G'/G''$ is either torsion-free or has only torsion elements (and that $G/G'$ is a free ableian group).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read chapter $\;5.2\;$ of Robinson's "A Course in the Theory of Groups" , page 131 (2nd. Edition 1996), about torsion products and the lower central series. This will answer some of your doubts, if not all of them at least in the case of nilpotent groups.

Comment: I suspect this is not enough here. If he had hypotheses on $G/G'$ (say that it was torsion), then this would give a similar conclusion for all $G_i/G_{i+1}$. Unfortunately, it doesn't hold for torsion-free and I don't think one can use $G'/G''$ instead of $G/G'$. It'd be nice to have a counterexample though :-)

Comment: Ah, $G$ infinite dihedral. Then $G'/G''$ is infinite cyclic, but $G_i/G_{i+1}$ has order 2 for all $i \geq 2$.

Comment: Well, Robinson's work with torsion products for the lower central series is focused on nilpotent groups. But for this the lower central series doesn't end or it gets stuck somewhere in the middle...much harder to control.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. In fact, for the groups I'm interested in them, $G/G'$ is torsion-free, isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^n$, and $G'/G''$ has only torsion elements (this is the reason for the "edit" I added).

Comment: Since $$G'' < G_4 < G_3 < G_2=G' < G,$$


so if $G'/G''$ is torsion, obviously $G'/G_3$ and $G_3/G_4$ are also torsion. I think that this implies every $G_k/G_{k+1}$ is torsion, because if $\gamma^n$ is in G_4 for some element in $G_3$, then $[\gamma,x]^n = [\gamma^n,x]=1$ in $G_4/G_5$, and so on. Is this correct?